# How to embed the Snapkit Login Button in a Compose UI

Tags: android, snapchat

The Snapkit login API provides a style button to initiate login. However it uses a View Group.  How to use this inside of a Compose UI?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
private fun SnapLoginButton() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    AndroidView(factory = {
        FrameLayout(context).also {
            SnapLogin.getButton(context, it)
        }
    })
}
```

After login you can fetch user data

```
    private fun fetchUserDatax() {
        val query = "{me{displayName bitmoji{avatar} externalId}}"
        SnapLogin.fetchUserData(this, query, mapOf(), object : FetchUserDataCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(p0: UserDataResponse?) {
                state = "onSuccess " + p0?.data?.me?.displayName + " " + p0?.errors?.map { it.errorType }
            }

            override fun onFailure(p0: Boolean, p1: Int) {
                state = "onFailure " + p0 + " " + p1
            }
        })
    }
```